# Python coding and testing

Tags: python, web-services, terminal

Hi there I'm trying to test my code in a separate testing folder but every time i try and perform a python3 test on it, it says NameError: name 'word_count' is not defined even though I've imported the folder that has this name defined as you can see? Can anyone help?  `

wordcount code:

```
def word_count(str): 
counts = dict()
words = str.split()

for word in words:
    if word in counts:
        counts[word] += 1
    else:
        counts[word] = 1

return counts`
```

Testing code:

```
import wordcount 
print(word_count('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'))
```

Comment: Can you share how your code is co-located? Is it inside the same directory?

Comment: Yeah they are both under the same directory but i can't figure out why its not seeing the import

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the function  word_count from the module wordcount (if your file is named wordcount.py), i.e.:

```
from wordcount import word_count
print(word_count('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'))
```

Or use the module name as a prefix for your function

```
import wordcount
    print(wordcount.word_count('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'))
```

Comment: That resolved it , Thanks you for that! I just assumed importing the file alone would input all its parentheses as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with `wordcount.word_count(...)` if `wordcount.py` and your `test_script.py` is in the same folder. Or you can use this import statement: `from wordcount import word_count`.

Comment: That resolved it , Thanks you for that! I just assumed importing the file alone would input all its parentheses as well.